# JSon REST API. Retrieving items in lists. Workflows

Tags: rest, designer-workflow, json

Using this:
http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=224

I was able to make a workflow that loops through lists.

Now I understand adding `?$top=5000` at the end of my URL I can pull more than 100 results. however I need to pull about 41000 results. I know it caps at 100. Can someone post how I would do this. I see references to `__next` and `$skiptoken` but I dont understand where/how to put this in my workflow.

I would like to be able to build the list dictionary 100 results at a time. If I could figure this out it would be easy but I dont understand how to get it working. I have tried a lot, nothing has worked. Please.

Answer (score 0):

`$top` returns `__next` with the response. So you have to make another GET request to get more items.

First call end-point looks like

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('list')/Items?$top=1
```

In the response, you will find

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [],
        "__next": "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/Intranet/fm/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('Workorders')/Items?%24skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_ID%3d1&%24top=1"
    }
}
```

That means, you have to make another GET request to `response.d.__next`. You have to make this request until it returns no `__next` inside your workflow.

Comment: I am using this interface and have no clue how to do what you are saying. http://imgur.com/OzhowZH When I do a get of d/__next nothing happens.

Comment: Wouldnt this still limit me to 5000 items. How do I start my next Call at a higher value so I can pull past the first 5000.

Comment: d/__next  is not the valid syntax I guess. Response is a dictionary. so you have to access it through a Key

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I've found some useful information.  First, for SharePoint 2013 you'll need to add `$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&$top=20` to your REST URL and not just `?$top=20`
Next, to retrieve the *next URL* from the response, you'll need to add the following action to your workflow:

```
Get d/__next from Variable: JSONResults (Output to Variable: nextlink)
```

Oh, and the link to the how-to has been updated above - https://wonderlaura.com/2014/8/1/workflow-loop-through-multiple-sharepoint-items/